# Average CI CD duration on Gitlab

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, gitlab

I'm new to gitlab and AWS EC2 and still learning .

I'm having a pipeline on gitlab to deploy an n-tiers app with 2 front in angular and a backend in Java spring boot + postgresql .

I'm doing the ng build on gitlab server then push it to my ec2 with an rsync , and for the spring part i do the ".tar " generation on my ec2 with some caching method it takes less than 20s to fully update the backend so theres not much problem there .

Each part containerized under docker with docker compose , i have to do  docker-compose build no cache to take fresh data .

It takes 3 mn 38s to fully upload all parts of my app and around 2mn if i want to upload only one part ( like for exemple i want update only one of my front with a specific job) .

Is it too long or i am on an average time for CI CD ?

If you guys know other better way or more standard to push to production containerized app to AWS EC2 feel free to tell me .

thanks !

Comment: this is faster than our builds, but we have huge geoscience environments. if you need to really tune your build time you could push your containers to the google `us-east1` region (which is [where gitlab.com runs](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/engineering/infrastructure/production/architecture/)) or use your own runners co-located with your registry.

Comment: I'm not pushing containers i'm pushing the dist folder i've generated inside my gitlab runner to my ec2 using rsync command then on my ec2 i launch docker-compose build ---no-cache and on my dockerfile execution do  COPY dist from host to html/ of my containers . 
Can you give me more information about your push containers way please ?